# React Native: Unable to resolve module ./CameraRollView

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native.  All I am trying to do is implement the [cameraroll example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html) that ReactNative has on their website.

I have copied their code exactly:

```
'use strict';

const React = require('react');
const ReactNative = require('react-native');
const {
  CameraRoll,
  Image,
  Slider,
  StyleSheet,
  Switch,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity
} = ReactNative;

const CameraRollView = require('./CameraRollView');

const AssetScaledImageExampleView = require('./AssetScaledImageExample');

const CAMERA_ROLL_VIEW = 'camera_roll_view';

class CameraRollExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    groupTypes: 'SavedPhotos',
    sliderValue: 1,
    bigImages: true,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Switch
          onValueChange={this._onSwitchChange}
          value={this.state.bigImages} />
        <Text>{(this.state.bigImages ? 'Big' : 'Small') + ' Images'}</Text>
        <Slider
          value={this.state.sliderValue}
          onValueChange={this._onSliderChange}
        />
        <Text>{'Group Type: ' + this.state.groupTypes}</Text>
        <CameraRollView
          ref={CAMERA_ROLL_VIEW}
          batchSize={20}
          groupTypes={this.state.groupTypes}
          renderImage={this._renderImage}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  loadAsset = (asset) => {
    if (this.props.navigator) {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'Camera Roll Image',
        component: AssetScaledImageExampleView,
        backButtonTitle: 'Back',
        passProps: { asset: asset },
      });
    }
  };

  _renderImage = (asset) => {
    const imageSize = this.state.bigImages ? 150 : 75;
    const imageStyle = [styles.image, {width: imageSize, height: imageSize}];
    const location = asset.node.location.longitude ?
      JSON.stringify(asset.node.location) : 'Unknown location';
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity key={asset} onPress={ this.loadAsset.bind( this, asset ) }>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Image
            source={asset.node.image}
            style={imageStyle}
          />
          <View style={styles.info}>
            <Text style={styles.url}>{asset.node.image.uri}</Text>
            <Text>{location}</Text>
            <Text>{asset.node.group_name}</Text>
            <Text>{new Date(asset.node.timestamp).toString()}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  _onSliderChange = (value) => {
    const options = CameraRoll.GroupTypesOptions;
    const index = Math.floor(value * options.length * 0.99);
    const groupTypes = options[index];
    if (groupTypes !== this.state.groupTypes) {
      this.setState({groupTypes: groupTypes});
    }
  };

  _onSwitchChange = (value) => {
    this.refs[CAMERA_ROLL_VIEW].rendererChanged();
    this.setState({ bigImages: value });
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
  },
  url: {
    fontSize: 9,
    marginBottom: 14,
  },
  image: {
    margin: 4,
  },
  info: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

exports.title = 'Camera Roll';
exports.description = 'Example component that uses CameraRoll to list user\'s photos';
exports.examples = [
  {
    title: 'Photos',
    render(): ReactElement<any> { return <CameraRollExample />; }
  }
];
```

However, when I run this in the simulator I get the following error:

```
My-Computer:AwesomeProject david$ react-native log-ios
Sep 21 10:01:17 My-Computer AwesomeProject[2102] <Error>: [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
--- last message repeated 1 time ---
Sep 21 10:01:17 My-Computer AwesomeProject[2102] <Critical>: Unable to resolve module ./CameraRollView from /Users/david/projects/react/react_native/AwesomeProject/index.ios.js: Unable to find this module in its module map or any of the node_modules directories under /Users/david/projects/react/react_native/AwesomeProject/CameraRollView and its parent directories

    This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
    To resolve try the following:
      1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
      2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
      3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
```

I tried doing the 3 steps they tell me but they don't work.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create another component in your project directory named `CameraRollView.js`. You can find the related code here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/js/CameraRollView.js

Comment: Why isn't that in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks, also I tried doing that.  I added CameraRollView.js to the root directory of the project but I still get the same error

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the same error? Try adding `AssetScaledImageExample.js` from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/js/AssetScaledImageExample.js. I don't know why it's not in docs.

Comment: Tried that but still the exact same error.  Am I supposed to edit package.json?

Comment: OK, this is really weird.  I've completely removed all references to CameraRollView and I'm still getting the exact same error.

Comment: Make sure you are modifying the right files, sometimes you have two copies of the same repository and things get messed up. Try erasing all the code and do a simple component to make sure everything is ok, then add `require` lines to see if the problem persists. Then try adding the rest of the code.